# Concordância verbal: "X tal como Y é" ou "X tal como Y são"?

Tags: sintaxe, concordância-verbal

No outro dia eu ia a escrever

> (a) *Franqueado* tal como *franqueador* são usados na lei brasileira,

mas fiquei com duvidas sobre se estaria correto; se não teria que obrigatoriamente ser

> (b) *Franqueado*, tal como *franqueador*, é usado na lei brasileira.

Eu não tenho dúvida que (b) está correta. A minha dúvida é se (a), possivelmente com uma ou duas vírgulas, também está. E no caso de estar, qual é a pontuação correta? Eu estaria tentado a colocar uma vírgula após *franqueado*, para assinalar uma ligeira pausa na fala:

> (c) *Franqueado*, tal como *franqueador* são usados na lei brasileira.

Mas parece-me algo estranho separar os dois únicos termos de um sujeito por uma vírgula. Para esgotar todas as possibilidades, admitamos uma segunda vírgula, pontuando como em (b):

> (d) *Franqueado*, tal como *franqueador*, são usados na lei brasileira.

Mas isto, apesar de haver talvez uma ligeiríssima pausa na fala após *franqueador*, parece-me muito estranho: nós usamos normalmente estes pares de vírgulas para isolar comentários parentéticos, mas eu não quero que “tal como *franqueador*” seja um comentário parentético; quero que seja parte do sujeito (caso contrário o verbo teria de ir para o singular, e voltávamos à (b)).

Finalmente podem-me dizer para escrever “*franqueado* e *franqueador* são”, que foi o que eu acabei por fazer. Mas eu queria “tal como” e não “e”, por razões que não vem ao caso. E portanto, preciso de saber se (a) com pontuação correta é possível.

Comment: Eu considero que o trecho entre vírgulas, parênteses ou travessões é uma frase à parte: "_Franqueado_ é usado na lei brasileira. Tal como _franqueador_." Como se fosse um "comentário", no contexto computacional.

Comment: @Ramon, mas queres com isso dizer simplesmente que a (d) está errada (tendo a concordar) ou que a (b) é a única correta, que *tal como franqueador* tem obrigatoriamente de vir entre vírgulas (é a minha dúvida)?

Comment: `(c)` e `(d)` estão definitivamente erradas. `(b)` está decididamente correta. Já sobre a `(c)`, eu não sei mesmo. Por isto que estou a lhe deixar comentários. :P

Comment: Quando as vírgulas são usadas, a função sintática de "tal como franqueador" é-me clara: _Franqueado é usado da mesma forma que franqueador na lei brasileira_ (advérbio de modo). Mas, quando as vírgulas desaparecem, não consigo mais compreender a função de "tal como franqueador". Como estas frases diferem de significado? Acho que a resposta está por aí.

Comment: @Ramon, no fundo eu quero em (a) usar *tal como* com função conjuntiva, acho. O Bruno, vê a resposta dele, encontrou no uol *bem como* usado desse modo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As frases `(a)`, `(b)` e `(c)` estão corretas mas têm elementos gramaticais diferentes.
Neste exemplo particular, mesmo com elementos gramaticais diferentes, elas transmitem apenas uma ideia que não está sujeita a várias interpretações.

A ideia é que "Quer Franqueado quer franqueador são usados na lingua brasileira."

As frases `(a)` e `(c)` são idênticas e poderiam ser substituídas pela seguinte:

> Franqueado e franqueador são usados na lei brasileira

A única diferenca é que na frase `(c)` o sujeito composto foi separado, facultativamente, por vírgulas.

---

Já a frase `(b)` não poderia ser substituida por esta mesma frase.

A razao é que o sujeito é composto nas frases `(a)` e `(c)` `Franqueado tal como franqueador`. Enquanto na frase `(b)` o sujeito é simples `Franqueado`<sup>[1](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint53.php)</sup>.

Pode-se então chegar-se á conclusão que o verbo ser foi devidamente conjugado em ambas as frases.

Nas frases `(a)` e `(c)` o verbo é conjugado na terceira pessoa do plural `Franqueado(,) tal como franqueador (eles)`.

Na frase `(b)` o verbo é conjugado na terceira pessoa do singular `Franqueado (ele)`

Uma outra forma de verificar que a frase `(b)` está bem formada é tentar deslocar a proposição explicativa para o fim da frase.

> Franqueado é usado na lei brasileira, tal como franqueador.

A frase `(d)` está incorrecta, pois não é correto separar o sujeito do predicado.<sup>[1](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-virgula-o-sujeito-e-o-predicado/22857), [2](https://educacao.uol.com.br/dicas-portugues/ult2781u519.jhtm)</sup>

---

[O artigo publicado no portugues uol](http://portugues.uol.com.br/gramatica/bem-como-assim-como-como-particularidades.html) apoia a minha resposta, contudo eles dão um exemplo para "bem como" equivalente á expressão "tal como"

Comment: Portanto, dizes que *tal como* é uma locução legítima para ligar dois termos de um sujeito? Os sites que linkas não dizem nada sobre o assunto.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, nao encontrei nada que prove nem desminta. Se encontrar atualizo a resposta.

Comment: @Jacinto Encontrei uma fonte que confirma o já dito.

Comment: Sim, *tal como* é até equivalente simplesmente a *como*, que eles também tá têm.

Comment: @BrunoCosta O link que você postou está com o certificado comprometido (não está confirmando o dono do site). Não sei se é um problema temporário, mas talvez seja mais seguro se você puder substituí-lo por um link arquivado: http://archive.is/ul3lH